# how do I make pyramid in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops

I tried to make pyramid with the length 4

this is code I have tried

```
console.log("-----------------------")


function middle(){

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        var output = '';
        for(j=1; j < 4 - i; j++)
            output += ' ';
        for (k =1; k <=(2*i+1); k++)
            output += '*';
        console.log(output);
     
    }
}

middle();
```

I got output

```
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

But I want to achieve output like this

[image]

Comment: If this is restricted to a console output, you physically can't.  As console outputs are generally fixed width font size.   If your output can be HTML then this would be a lot easier.  One idea though, if this is console output, find something that uses 2 chars,..   eg.. `()`, and then you can have half space that will allow your systematical pyramid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use loops to generate multiple characters - use String's repeat() function instead:

```js
function middle(){
    let s = "";
    for (let i = 4; i >= 0; i--){
        s += " ".repeat(i) + "* ".repeat(4 - i) + "\n";
    }
    return s;
}

console.log(middle());
```

Note that the empty spaces are actually non-breaking spaces - character code 160.  As this outputs in monospace characters, the formatting will be ok.  On a page, though, you would have to set the font-family to "monospace" to achieve the same effectc.

Answer (score 2):

You're likely using a monospaced font.

This means that all characters have the the same width.

This is handy in computer programming as it's more readable when things line up.

This means that it's not possible set a character 'halfway' between two others, unless you use spaces, like:

```
   *
  * *
 * * *
```

In which case, it's just matter of adjusting your loops to include spaces in the right places.

Answer (score 1):

Seen as your question doesn't state that this has to use Console output, here is a version were the output is HTML / Webpage.

```js
const pyramid = document.querySelector('#pyramid');
for (let l = 1; l <= 4; l +=1) {
  const p = document.createElement('div');
  p.innerText = '⭐'.repeat(l);
  pyramid.appendChild(p);
}
```

```css
#pyramid {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div id="pyramid">
</div>
```

Comment: Update it for 4 as the OP suggested, then, I think, it's a snazzy way to output to the page!  I've given it a thumb's up anyway.

Comment: @ATD  good point, updated.  I used his pic instead, but he did state 4 in his question.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need :-

```js
const renderTree = () => {
  const noOfColums = Number(document.getElementById("inputNumber").value);
  let finalTree = "";
  const STAR = "*";
  const SPACE = "&nbsp&nbsp";
  for (let rowNumber = 1; rowNumber <= noOfColums; rowNumber++) {
    let row = "";
    const starStarIndex = noOfColums - rowNumber;
    for (let j = 0; j < starStarIndex; j++) {
      row += SPACE;
    }
    for (let j = 0; j < rowNumber; j++) {
      row += STAR + SPACE;
    }
    row += "<br>";
    finalTree += row;
  }
  const div = document.getElementById("output");
  div.innerHTML = finalTree;
};
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById("inputNumber").addEventListener("change", renderTree);
};
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TREE</title>
    <script src="./tree.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <input id= "inputNumber" onchange="renderTree">Input your number</input>
    <div>
        Tree is :-
        <div id="output"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```